# Can someone explain why this prolog query evaluates to false?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying to write a predicate `pythagorean(X,Y,Z,W)` that can generate all triples such that `X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2`, where `W >= X,Y,Z > 0`.

This is what I wrote:

```
pyth(X,Y,Z,W) :-
   X > 0, 
   Y > 0,
   Z > 0,
   S1 is X*X + Y*Y,
   S2 is Z*Z, 
   S1 == S2,
   W  @> Z.
```

Comment: "... where 0..." - is there a bit missing from your question?

Comment: If you are trying to *generate* triples, then `X`, `Y` and `Z` are uninstantiated, which will cause a problem with `X > 0`.

Comment: I've tried to include it several times but form some reason it's not showing up. This is the remaining part of the question : "where 0<X,Y,Z <=W."

Comment: How would I instantiate them?

Comment: *You* don't; you get Prolog to.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define `pytri/2` based on the FD-constraints [`sum/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), [`chain/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), [`(#=)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), and [`(#<)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html):

```
pytri(Zs,Perimeter) :-
   Zs = [A,B,C],
   maplist(#<(1),Zs),
   sum(Zs,#=,Perimeter),
   chain(Zs,#<),
   A^2 + B^2 #= C^2.
```

Let's find all 17 [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) (16 primitive + 1 non-primitive) having a perimeter ≤ 100:

```
?- pytri([X,Y,Z],Perimeter), Perimeter #=< 100, labeling([],[Z,Y,X]).
  Perimeter = 12, X =  3, Y =  4, Z =  5
; Perimeter = 24, X =  6, Y =  8, Z = 10
; Perimeter = 30, X =  5, Y = 12, Z = 13
; Perimeter = 36, X =  9, Y = 12, Z = 15
; Perimeter = 40, X =  8, Y = 15, Z = 17
; Perimeter = 48, X = 12, Y = 16, Z = 20
; Perimeter = 60, X = 15, Y = 20, Z = 25
; Perimeter = 56, X =  7, Y = 24, Z = 25
; Perimeter = 60, X = 10, Y = 24, Z = 26
; Perimeter = 70, X = 20, Y = 21, Z = 29
; Perimeter = 72, X = 18, Y = 24, Z = 30
; Perimeter = 80, X = 16, Y = 30, Z = 34
; Perimeter = 84, X = 21, Y = 28, Z = 35
; Perimeter = 84, X = 12, Y = 35, Z = 37
; Perimeter = 90, X = 15, Y = 36, Z = 39
; Perimeter = 96, X = 24, Y = 32, Z = 40
; Perimeter = 90, X =  9, Y = 40, Z = 41
; false.                                   % terminates universally
```

Answer (score 0):

If `X`, `Y` or `Z` aren't bound to numbers, your `<` tests will fail.  And even if you supply values (testing a triple instead of generating them), I'm not sure that `@>` is a legal predicate.

This uses `inrange` to take care of coming up with candidates for X, Y and Z (assuming they are integers).  Note that, since you did not put constraints on the relative values of X & Y, you'll get "duplicate" answers.

```
pyth(X,Y,Z,W) :- W1 is W-1,
    inrange(X,1,W1), inrange(Y,1,W1), inrange(Z,1,W1),
    S1 is X* X + Y* Y, S2 is  Z*Z, S1 == S2.

% inrange(A,B,C) B <= A <= C
inrange( V, V, _ ).
inrange( V, L, H ) :- L < H, L2 is L + 1, inrange( V, L2, H ).
```

Comment: Can you please explain how your inrange works and how you did you get prolog to instantiate X,Y and Z?